# App instant crash after loading: A module failed to load due to an error

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, macos-sonoma

I'm not sure because the project haven't been touched in months but it seems that the problem did appear after I upgraded MacOS to Sonoma. I am on an Intel Mac.

A fully working app doesn't run at all and instantly crash at start with the following error message:

```bash
iOS Bundled 411ms (index.js)
 LOG  Running "" with {"rootTag":21,"initialProps":{}}
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

So I updated all my npm packages/reinstalled the pods, I now have:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "npx expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "build:ios": "eas build -p ios",
    "build:android": "eas build -p android",
    "build:all": "eas build -p all",
    "publish:ios": "eas submit -p ios",
    "publish:android": "eas submit -p android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.22.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "expo": "^50.0.8",
    "expo-clipboard": "^5.0.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "^3.3.9",
    "expo-font": "^11.10.3",
    "expo-image-picker": "^14.7.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^12.7.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.26.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.11.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.73.5",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^13.0.2",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^5.0.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3"
  },
```

But the app still fails running. So I replaced my index.js by the following content (just to try if my App.js could be the problem):

```js
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import { View } from 'react-native';

function App() {
  return <View />;
}
// Utilisation de registerRootComponent pour les applications Expo
registerRootComponent(App);
```

I have in my app.json:

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "AppName",
    "displayName": "AppName",[...]
```

I also tried using AppRegistry directly but I still have the same error message. And the moduleName is set to @"main" in my AppDelegate.mm

Answer (score 0):

At first I'll suggest to close everything and load it again.
Next, change your index.js to be

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

After that change the App.js back to what it was and try to run it again.

btw, when you run the app for the first time without changes does it run ? and what the react native version that you have?

Comment: No it does't work, still the same error by changing my index.js to what you gave me.

I can't load the app at all since I upgraded my OS ! The react version is 0.73.3

Comment: when you run it for the first time after creating new app you get this error ? if so, I believe that the environment is not configured right.

Comment: As I said it's an old project that haven't been touched in months, so yes it was fully working ! And the app is available on both stores. When I wanted to update the app after a few month and an OS update I got this error

Comment: That must be related to the OS update. that can happen when you update xCode or android studio.  is it possible to watch the repo ? that can be due to packages update also. btw, when you build android with gradle doe's the build failed or success ? same for ios

Answer (score 0):

- The significant changes introduced in React Native 0.64.0. In this version, the AppRegistry module has been removed and replaced with AppRegistry.registerComponent.
- In your index.js file, you're using registerRootComponent from 'expo'. This method is no longer available in the latest version of Expo. You need to use AppRegistry.registerComponent instead.

You can modify your index.js file

```
  import { registerComponent } from 
  'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';
  import App from './App';

  //RegisterComponent Utilisation for Expo Applications
  registerComponent(App);
```

Or, if you prefer to use AppRegistry.registerComponent directly

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

//RegisterComponent Utilisation for Expo Applications
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AppName', () => App);
```

Comment: I started the project using RN 0.70.5, so I don't think it can be the cause of the crash here. I tried both solutions you wrote me be still the same error from my side !